# Python troubles (classes, SUPER BASIC)

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

So I was messing around with python classes and I had trouble understanding it, this is what I came up with

```
class Forest:
    def temperature (self,temperature):
        self.temperature=temperature
    def displayTemp (self):
        return self.temperature
    def saying(self):
        print "This soup is %s" % self.displayTemp  

first=Forest()
second=Forest()
third=Forest()

first.temperature('too cold.')
second.temperature('warm.')
third.temperature('too hot.')

temperature=input("1~10; How hot is the soup? ")
int(temperature)

if (temperature<=3):
    first.saying
elif (temperature==4,5,6):
    second.saying
else:
    third.saying
```

the goal was for it to ask a question like `"1~10; How hot is the soup? "` and then you put in a number  (1-3 = too cold; 4-6 warm; 7-10 too hot) but instead of calling back the response it doesn't do anything.

I'm totally new to python and I have looked around but my lack of understanding makes it harder for me and I read a couple things here on what I thought it might be, but no luck.

Comment: `temperature==4,5,6` is equivalent to `(temperature==4),5,6`, i.e an non-empty tuple, which is always `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

By itself `first.saying` is just a reference to the function object; you need parentheses to actually call it: `first.saying()`, `second.saying()`, etc.  You need to do the same with `self.displayTemp()`.

Also, `int(temperature)` doesn't change the value of `temperature`; it returns a *new* value that is converted to int.  If you want to replace the old value, you need to do `temperature = int(temperature)`.

Also `temperature==4,5,6` won't do what you seem to want.  You need to do something like `4 <= temperature <= 6`.

You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) to get familiar with the basics of Python.

Comment: also comparision in the form of x==4,5,6 does something different then expected

Comment: omg! thank you so much! I was watching these videos from thenewboston.org so I thought I had a good grasp on it but I guess a couple things slipped past me, thank you very much!